# Process image during CATransition animation with GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, catransition

I'm trying to set the image back to default when i shake the device. the problem is that, the image is processing to default and only afterwards the rippleEffect happens.

I'm trying to do this during the animation, not before nor after.
any ideas?

```
    -(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
         if(motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake){
            CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
            [animation setDelegate:self];
            [animation setDuration:1.0];
            [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
            [animation setType:@"rippleEffect"];
            //[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeRemoved];
            animation.endProgress=0.99;

            [(GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter *)sepiaFilter setScale:0.0];
            [sourcePicture processImage];

            [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
            [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
        }
    }
```